# Coloring specific elements in a string

Tags: javascript, for-loop, brackets

I'm working on a code to color all the curly brackets from my input field (textt). I have no problem finding them using a for and if statement, but i cant seem to color them or even make them bold. This is what i have currently:

```
function colorBrackets() {

    var string = document.getElementById("textt").value;

    var a = string.split(" ");

    var result = "";

    for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
        if((a[i] == "{") || (a[i] == "}"))   {   
            a[i].style.color = "blue";
        }
    }
    //brackets is my output field
    document.getElementById("brackets").value = result;
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: You can't style things in this manner in an input field, even if you purely used html/css.  You'd need to parse the input as you're doing, but display the colouring within some other element that supports more complex markup.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, so i need to wrap the specific a[i] in for example a span and then color that span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert spans around the part of the text you want to color.

- I just replaced the { and } in the text with { and } surrounded by styled spans.
- Then appended it back as innerHTML and voila.

```js
function colorBrackets() {
    let string = document.getElementById("input").innerText;
    let result = string.replace(/{|}/g, '<span style="color: red">$&</span>');
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result;
}
colorBrackets();
```

```html
<div id="input">{Hello }</div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

PS: This wouldn't work inside an input field. Since the `value` of an `input` has to be a string and not HTML. But the good news is that you can apply it in a `div` with `contenteditable = true`.

Comment: Nice! can u elaborate /({)|(})/g? is this regex?

Comment: Yes it is. More about regular expressions here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp. The g flag makes sure it matches all occasions. | means or. $& is a reference to the element that is being replaced. I don't think you actually need the ( and ) in this case. I'll edit that out :).